# Do I need to specify kernel modules in a particular order while using modprobe to insert them?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a list of modules in a shell script variable, lets call it `modulelist`. Some of those modules are already loaded.

I am  doing `modprobe -a $modulelist` and running into a segmentation fault, which is due to one of the modules that is being loaded.

My question is : Do I have to modify the order in which module names are specified in the variable modulelist ? I thought that the order of modules in the list would not make a difference since modprobe -a loads the modules and the modules they depend on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't matter, and it definitely shouldn't segfault.

Answer (score 2):

not sure how much it will help you  but maybe you should try to run with either  --show-depends  or -n -v options and see if more information help diagnose the issue

also you might want to check the depmod command which is concerned with creating dependency list